# Glass Mirror API service - How to get Mirror server object?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

How do we get reference to service object in the java example?

https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/list

Answer (score 2):

From the quickstart sample code at https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java (and, in particular https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/glassware/MirrorClient.java) you can get a Mirror object through the builder using code like

```
public static Mirror getMirror(Credential credential) {
  return new Mirror.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
      .setApplicationName("PG Java Starter").build();
}
```

See also the JavaDoc at 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mirror/v1/java/latest/